# storing image as physical file on server

Tags: java, struts2

I am getting problem in storing images fetched from some url.The problem is where to store image on server and what path is to be given on database.how to store images on server as a physical files and then later on retrieve that image on jsp page.

Comment: See struts 2 file upload interceptor

Comment: possible duplicate of [Storing Images in java project dynamically](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/27163585/storing-images-in-java-project-dynamically)

Answer (score 0):

You should make a folder in the project, use this folder to store physical files and give its path in action.

Online example is [here](https://github.com/prem30488/ImageDatabaseExample/archive/master.zip) to store image from database to specific folder.

[Download Code here](https://github.com/prem30488/ImageDatabaseExample/archive/master.zip) - [Project URL](https://github.com/prem30488/ImageDatabaseExample)

Your modification is not to store in db but store in your folder, for example if you have stored files in folder "images"

> System.out.println(request.getRealPath("/")+"images\"+"YourFileName"+".jpg");

Above code will give you path of physical path on server.

Your Question is possible duplicate of

[Struts2: How to store images outside of the webapp and save its path to the db?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13916006/struts2-how-to-store-images-outside-of-the-webapp-and-save-its-path-to-the-db?rq=1)

[Storing Images in java project dynamically](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/27163585/storing-images-in-java-project-dynamically?lq=1)